# Snakemake with multiple output directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, snakemake

I'm new to using snakemake. I've written a bash script to analyse some paired end amplicon sequencing data. I've been advised to use snakemake to iterate my script over the paired reads for each sample. My script generates lots of different output files (various bams, vcfs, html and txt files) in different directories (qc, alignment, variants, consensus and repeats).

I've read the [tutorial](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html), and tried writing a Snakefile, as below. I didn't know what to put in output as there are many different output directories and files created, so I thought having input and script would be enough.

```
rule othello_call:
    input:
        R1="/Users/michaelflower/Documents/ACL/Research/Projects/Illumina amplicon sequencing/2021.03.23 MiSeq test/run_othello/data/{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz"
        R2="/Users/michaelflower/Documents/ACL/Research/Projects/Illumina amplicon sequencing/2021.03.23 MiSeq test/run_othello/data/{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz"
        GEN="hg38"
        REF="/Users/michaelflower/refs/hg38/hg38.fa"
        REPREF="/Users/michaelflower/refs/monckton/Supplementary_Data.fasta"
        CON="/Users/michaelflower/opt/anaconda3"
        OUT="/Users/michaelflower/Documents/ACL/Research/Projects/Illumina amplicon sequencing/2021.03.23 MiSeq test/run_othello"
    output:
    shell:
        ./othello.sh R1={input.R1} \
            R2={input.R2} \
            GEN={input.GEN} \
            REF={input.REF} \
            REPREF={input.REPREF} \
            CON={input.CON} \
            OUT={input.OUT}
```

But when I run it I get:

```
$ snakemake -np
SyntaxError in line 8 of /Users/michaelflower/bin/othello/Snakefile:
invalid syntax (Snakefile, line 8)
```

Any help setting up the input and output rules would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your snakemake:

1. Inputs and outputs should be separated by commas `,`
2. Inputs and outputs are files (or folders). "hg38" should be in the `params` section.
3. Outputs are mandatory since snakemake is a "top to bottom" workflow manager. It is by their outputs that rules are triggered.
4. You have spaces in your folder names which is not recommanded at all since the shell commands will consider them as multiple arguments.
5. the `shell` section should be surrounded by quotes `"` or triple quotes block `"""`

The errors that lead to you "invalid syntax" is probably the lack of commas to separate your inputs.

I guess your Snakefile should look something like this:

```
SAMPLES = ["SAMPLE1","SAMPLE2","SAMPLE3"]

rule all:
    input: expand("/Users/michaelflower/Documents/ACL/Research/Projects/Illumina_amplicon_sequencing/2021.03.23_MiSeq_test/run_othello/results/{sample}/fileProducedByOthello.txt", sample=SAMPLES)

rule othello_call:
    input:
        R1="/Users/michaelflower/Documents/ACL/Research/Projects/Illumina_amplicon_sequencing/2021.03.23_MiSeq_test/run_othello/data/{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2="/Users/michaelflower/Documents/ACL/Research/Projects/Illumina_amplicon_sequencing/2021.03.23_MiSeq_test/run_othello/data/{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz",
        REF="/Users/michaelflower/refs/hg38/hg38.fa",
        REPREF="/Users/michaelflower/refs/monckton/Supplementary_Data.fasta",
        CON="/Users/michaelflower/opt/anaconda3",
    output:
        OUT="/Users/michaelflower/Documents/ACL/Research/Projects/Illumina_amplicon_sequencing/2021.03.23_MiSeq_test/run_othello/{sample}/fileProducedByOthello.txt"
    params: 
        GEN="hg38"
    shell:
        """
        ./othello.sh R1={input.R1} \
            R2={input.R2} \
            GEN={params.GEN} \
            REF={input.REF} \
            REPREF={input.REPREF} \
            CON={input.CON} \
            OUT={output.OUT}
        """
```

This code is just here to guide you in creating your workflow.

- Note that snakemake can manage your conda environments. If you define the main installation path as an input, snakemake will want to rerun your rule everytime the timestamp gets updated (ie creating/modifying an environment).
- Main output files should be listed in `outputs` since snakemake will trigger the rules according to the files there.
- Moreover, your "othello" program seems like a workflow by itself if it creates many files. Maybe you should think about separating the steps of your programs into several snakemake rules.

Keep going with snakemake and I'm sure you'll like it ;)